# Exception in running spring hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi I Have implemented the spring and hibernate integration i have an exception while integrating the exceptions is:

Please Help Me to Solve This exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at test.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:14)
```

here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="test.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

here is the sample program:

```
> 
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  

import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

public class InsertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  Resource r=new ClassPathResource("test.xml");  
          //  BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);      
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");     
        EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)context.getBean("d");
            Employee e=new Employee();  
            e.setId(114);  
            e.setName("varun");  
            e.setSalary(50000);      
            dao.saveEmployee(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this the full exception stack trace? There should be a "caused by" below this part of the trace.

Comment: no its showing up to that only not showing the full stack trace here is the screenshot of stack trace : http://i.prntscr.com/tMMIezsXSDunb8cSVXmybg.png

Comment: Can you check if `applicationContext.xml` is in classpath and readable? Or try using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` and provide full path, instead of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. If this doesn't resolve it, post your java/spring versions and JARs in classpath. This could be a JAR clash or a known issue in older spring.

Comment: i am using eclipse these files are in root directory only here is the file structure: http://i.prntscr.com/o7TwRAVqTG262uqt3p8smQ.png

Comment: What is your spring version? Also, as I've suggested, please try `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` with path starting from project base folder.

Comment: here is the loaded jar files screenshot : http://i.prntscr.com/mBBXs0D7T4qtELrgBQ9iqQ.png anoter screenshot: http://i.prntscr.com/xjAS81qbS7Gls2R2iEAE7g.png

Comment: spring version and hibernate version are: 3.0.1 for spring and hibernate jar was : 3.3.2

Comment: That is a VERY old version of Spring, almost 8 years old. It might very well be a bug in Spring that was fixed. If `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` method doesn't work, you can try upgrading to a newer Spring version.

Comment: ok if was i use the new version 5.0 this error will resolved or not

Comment: i have replaced all the jars with new versions but this doesnot working this will gives some other exception see the screenshot for exception: http://i.prntscr.com/dX6FKmTdQuOi8lyichxR0A.png

Comment: Can you try using  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  in place of  
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">   in your applicationContext.xml file

Comment: is that driver manager data source will accept the other parameters there in the basic data source

Comment: I Have changed change the content to org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerData‌​Source and added the jar file also but it will give the exception like this: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerData‌​Source] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerData‌​Source

Comment: i have getting this exception after the drivers changing: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [test.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Comment: now it is working it is a jar conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just  Remove The All Added JAR files and try Adding each Jar file Carefully wont add the already added jar files this will work i have tested and working for mine